# Errata on ArXiv

Tags: arxiv, errors-erratum

Just a quick question. Is it appropriate to post updates on published papers on ArXiv? I am mostly thinking to use ArXiv as a place where to post papers including corrections (mostly technical typos). Thank you for your feedback. I’m mostly concerned by copyright issues and the fact that published papers cannot have more advanced versions published somewhere else.

Comment: Can you put the whole article on arxiv? It seems somewhat useless to just post errata.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to say to post papers including corrections in ArXiv. Mostly technical typos. I edited my question.

Comment: In case there is an issued erratum/corrigendum also see [Erratum or corrigendum on arXiv too? Should the authors lists match?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/117906/17254).